# Low and High frequency component of the solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

I'm having trouble to understand the following concept:
**Multigrid methods are based on the fact that for the low and high frequency components of the solution, different solution approaches are reasonable.**

Now, what it means a **frequency** associated to the elements of the solution vector ? Or maybe someone can suggest me some reading to understand more in general how the frequency are related to solution methods for linear systems ?

Thank you

Comment: It depends on the what is the system... Are you solving differential equations numerically?

Comment: Yes exactly! I don't have a specific problem, it is just a theoretical explanation the one that I found. In general how can you associate frequencies to components of a vector (that are numbers, not functions) ?

Comment: Cla, I'm not very familiar with the topic, but I'm pretty sure they mean the functions themselves. In other words, the numerical vectors are just approximations to the exact solution (which exists if the problem is well posed, just usually can't be found in terms of known functions). So they mean that the exact solution has two components with different frequencies, or in more general words, one is changing on a small scale and the other is changing on a large scale

Comment: Ok probably I have some gap to understanding well what you're saying! Can you maybe link me some reference to understand this "topic" a little better ?

Comment: As I said, I'm not well versed in the topic of multigrid methods. If there's a way to clarify my explanation, I could try, if you tell me what is it you don't understand about it

Comment: I don't get how frequencies are associated to vector components. What it means low and high frequencies in solution components ?

Comment: Cla, they are not. They are associated to functions *before* we even make the grid or the grid vectors. We represent the function as the two components one is varying of a large scale, one on a small scale. Then we make different grids for each of them, and different vectors to approximate them on those grids